# Insert post's category name into thumbnail string

Tags: post-thumbnails, categories

Hopefully a simple question. I've added several post thumbnail sizes to functions.php using add_image_size. They are each named exactly like a post category. I would like to find a way of making each post call the specific thumbnail size assigned to it's category.

The best way I can imagine doing it is by inserting the category name into the thumbnail string like so:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'INSERT CATEGORY NAME HERE' ); ?>
```

What could I put in this php string to make it insert the category's name into this?

Thank you.

Comment: The problem with this, if it does work, is that you can assign multiple categories to a post. So you're either going to have to enforce a single category policy on all your posts or you will have to pull out the first key of an array.

Comment: I didn't think of that. I suppose an array is something i'd have to factor in too. Or if possible, for it to just detect one of the 3 possible categories I was going to assign different size thumbnails too.

Comment: The thing is though, it's always going to look for the `[0]` key. So if you assign it category 1 and category 2, it will use 1's thumbnail always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @belinus mentioned, you can assign multiple categories to a post, so you have to decide which one to pass to `the_post_thumbnail()`.

One approach would be to use [`get_the_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/), which returns an array, then grabbing the first result from that function as your thumbnail size:

```
$categories    = get_the_category();
$thumbnail_cat = ! empty( $categories[0]->slug ) ? $categories[0]->slug : '';

the_post_thumbnail( $thumbnail_cat );
```

Comment: Hmm if I add this into a php tag it gives me this error:  `Warning:  Illegal offset type in isset or empty in /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/zwp/public/wp-includes/media.php on line 747
Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class WP_Term could not be converted to string in /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/zwp/public/wp-includes/media.php on line 884`

Comment: Oops, I missed that `get_the_category()` returns an array of `WP_Term` objects and not slugs. I've updated my answer to look for the term slug for the `$thumbnail_cat` string.

Comment: That fixed it! It's all working perfectly now. Thank you so much. You cleared up a big headache for me.